# Smaller size of CIFS mounted Directory than the file

Tags: files, disk-usage, cifs

I got a curious problem. I've copied some data from an external storage to a CIFS mounted directory over scp.

When I enter `ls -lah` in the CIFS mounted directory, I see that the file has 10 GB.

When I enter `du -mh` to see the size of the whole directory it says 1.5 GB.

What thing can cause this problem ? 
Many thanks in advance

[image: FileSize]

Comment: Use `-s` option to `ls`, to get disk usage.

Comment: Please do not paste text as an image, it makes if difficult for blind (and other including search engine, copy text when trying to find a solution …) user of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have a problem. That's because both commands show correct information. It's different, because `ls` shows the size of the file (when you open and read it, that's how many bytes you will get), while
`du` shows actual disk usage which can be smaller than the file size due to holes.

Comment: But I think I understand what you mean.. Many thanks

Comment: sparse files: no space is used for big gaps in the file. I am wondering is there a way to get `ls` to show same type of info as `du`.

Comment: I had a look. Using the `-s` option of `ls` shows how much space it uses.

Comment: Specifically, it sounds like scp is defaulting to `--sparse=auto`.  Some more info here: http://superuser.com/a/1079187/110495